# Unable to load previous version of Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have an old ASP.NET application on my hands ( about 10 years old ) and I'm trying to see it's functionality. Whenever I enter Debug mode ( I am already connected to the associated database for the app ) I get a RunTime error in Chrome.

In Visual Studio 2012 I get a build error stating:

> "Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.Web Version 10.5.37"

The thing is, I have already installed the latest version of Crystal Reports ( version 13 ) and I thought it would sovle the issue. Apparently not.

Anyone has any idea how could I make it work or find a workaround for it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I alreayd set the customError tag to Off to try and get a specific error message in Chrome, but no result.

Comment: Do you have respective dll in you bin directory?

Comment: no I do not have any dll file from Crystal Reports in the Bin directory ... I am trying to find out now what assembly contains CrystalDecisions.Web

Comment: So I just added the references to the Bin folder for the missing .DLL's and I still get the same error message